# Gated Checkins in TFS2010

Tags: msbuild, build-automation, tfsbuild

I wish to utilize the new gated check-in function of TFS 2010.

I have about 10 solutions, that all share as a dependency a proprietary shared-code library.

My structure is:

```
TeamProj/SharedCode
TeamProj/Proj1
TeamProj/Proj2
TeamProj/Proj3
........
```

The question I have is, how can I set-off an integration of ALL projects that have the SharedCode project as a dependency?

It's possible someone can make breaking changes, and not be aware of it until one of the other projects is opened/built manually.

I want to only trigger a big integration build when check-ins are made against the SharedCode folder.

The problem is, if I map the source-paths required to actually run the builds for the other projects, check-ins are picked-up automatically against all THOSE projects too.

How can I have a gated-checkin controlled folder that is independent to the source actually required to run a build?

Cheers,
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand right, you want to create a Build Definition as gated checkin that builds
TeamProj/Proj1, TeamProj/Proj2, TeamProj/Proj3 when any source file in TeamProj/SharedCode is changed?

In this case, one solution that comes to my mind is the following:

1. Create the build definition with only source folder TeamProj/SharedCode.
2. Change the build template to do a TFS GET for the other folders
3. Change the build template to build all the three solutions Proj{1,2,3}, not the SharedCode solution.

Is this what you want?

Comment: Mate - that sounds perfect - Can you give me any more information on how to do a TFS GET?

Comment: Of course I can, see http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/ for an msbuild solution (extension msbuild activities). What you need is a <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.VisualStudio.TfsSource TaskAction="Get"> activity.
For the new tfs2010 workflow based build templates, I don't have a solution yet, but I will come back later, as we also need an additional checkout (not quite getLatest, as you need, but the difference is minimal).